# Categories in Python with Pandas (special case)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have some data and want to build some categories.

Now, the data looks like this:

```
Var     Category
a         cat1
a         cat1
b         cat2
a         cat1
b         cat2
a         cat1
```

But it should look like this:

```
Var     Category
  a         cat1
  a         cat1
  b         cat2
  a         cat2
  b         cat3
  a         cat3
```

So, whenever 'Var' != 'a' 'Category' should move on to the next category and so on.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare for not equal and then add cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), add `1` if necessary, convert to strings and add to `cat`:

```
df['Category'] = 'cat' + df.Var.ne('a').cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
```

Alternative:

```
df['Category'] = 'cat' + (df.Var != 'a').cumsum().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
  Var Category
0   a     cat1
1   a     cat1
2   b     cat2
3   a     cat2
4   b     cat3
5   a     cat3
```